# Login Authentication Flow for Microservices

Tags: authentication, database-design, architecture, microservices

I recently just started and have been playing around with microservices. and there's a few things that confuses me.
first off for context, i want to create a separate MC for Auth and User and have this db schema for User

### user table

id, name, email, etc

### user_pass table

id, user_id, pass, salt, alg, etc

The question i have is the login flow authentication and i have narrowed down 3 options

1. a browser request gets sent to -> APIGateway -> User MC for pass details then message queues -> Auth MC -> validate --> send back token
2. a browser request gets sent to -> APIGateway -> Auth MC -> gets details straight from db -> validate -> send back token
3. a browser request gets sent to -> APIGateway -> User MC -> validate with small auth code -> send back token

I'm planning on just doing no.2 but i've read that it's bad to share db between MCs, so is it maybe the db schema that's the problem? 
Should i just make user_pass table a table specific for Auth MC's db and have it query from there? (UserDB.user_pass --->>> AuthDB.user_auth)

I'm also planning on just making the Auth MC as a ticket checker for JWT in every request or maybe filter that in the Gateway with the exception of the login flow no.2
but that's not any of my concerns right now as i know it could be very broad, my main concern right now is the login flow.

So please let me know what i'm doing wrong or if something is not clear. That would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user service should store everything about a user. So, it should provide an interface for validating a username-password pair. The database should not be exposed in my opinion. The auth service then simply delegates the validation to the user service (or maybe another identity provider). If successful, a JWT is returned to the client for all consecutive requests.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I was looking up other blogposts about this and found this https://elang2.github.io/myblog/posts/2018-08-02-api-gateway.html
Wouldn't it be better to have a centralized security layer for validating user and decoding access tokens that is hooked up into a data store? Although i'm not quite sure what a data store is or what's it's difference from a database.

Comment: It also seems complicated when dealing with passing other user related details (roles, permissions, etc.) to the access token if i rely heavily on that datastore and it kinda defeats the purpose of having database.
Or maybe use datastore for read and database for write purposes? I'm really torn on what to do.